Compute null space of a matrix in Python
I'm trying to understand how to implement equation (6) in this paper (in page 5). The equation is this:

With C, P are the emission matrix and state transition matrix in a HMM. The goal is to compute N.
Let's take the example 4 in this paper.

The result in the paper is given as:

Here's the code I used:
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import null_space

n = 4
P = np.array([[1/2, 0, 1/3, 1/4], [0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/4], [1/2, 0, 1/3, 0], [0, 2/3, 0, 1/2]])
C = np.array([[1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 7/16], [3/4, 3/4, 1/2, 9/16]])

N = C
for i in range(1, n):
    N = np.vstack((N, np.dot(C, np.linalg.matrix_power(P, i))))

ns = null_space(N)
print(ns)

The result from the code is this:
[[ 0.71390642 -0.01189748]
 [-0.68971636 -0.18464902]
 [ 0.07257016 -0.58963951]
 [-0.09676022  0.78618601]]

Both spans are equal but I want to know if there is anyway to get result in the paper using python.

Hi. Can you add some convincing argument that the results are different? Ie can you show that these two planes, Span((1,-1,0,0),(-1,0,-3,4)) from the paper and Span((0.71204526,...),(0.05287224,...)) from your computations, are not the same plane?

Thanks @Stef, I calculate rref of both spans and they are equal so they are indeed in the same plane, right? The code is then correct I guess. Is there anyway I can get the nice integer result as in the paper?

What do you mean by "rref"?

@Stef I'm assuming that means r"educed row echelon form".

yes, rref is the reduce row echelon form @Stef


In for i in range(1, n): shouldn't it be  for i in range(0, n-1): and 2) please post why you think they are different (or post what the authors claim to be the result.....or what you got on paper. With code, I get a differnt rsult than you.


@SergedeGossondeVarennes,

The loop is for calculating CP^i so it should start at 1 and end at n-1 as I have coded.
Update the question, both spans are equal. The result in paper are already in the question.


Interesting. Do you know if their calculations are made in the orthonormal basis for R^n? THis is the one used by scipy. Also, I do not get your code result I get array([[ 0.16383871,  0.69495381],        [-0.34842041, -0.62322319],        [-0.5537451 ,  0.21519187],        [ 0.7383268 , -0.2869225 ]])

Following what the paper does, your code should be
from scipy.linalg import svd

def compute_null_space(C, P, n):
    N = C
    for i in range(1, n):
        N = np.vstack((N, np.dot(C, np.linalg.matrix_power(P, i))))
    U, s, Vh = svd(N)
    tol = max(N.shape) * np.max(s) * np.finfo(s.dtype).eps
    null_mask = (s <= tol)
    null_space = Vh[null_mask, :]
    return null_space.T

P = np.array([[1/2, 0, 1/3, 1/4], [0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/4], [1/2, 0, 1/3, 0], [0, 2/3, 0, 1/2]])
C = np.array([[1/4, 1/4, 1/2, 7/16], [3/4, 3/4, 1/2, 9/16]])


ns_paper_method = compute_null_space(C, P, n=4)
ns_paper_method

which return
array([[ 0.16383871,  0.69495381],
       [-0.34842041, -0.62322319],
       [-0.5537451 ,  0.21519187],
       [ 0.7383268 , -0.2869225 ]])


I believe your compute_null_space function is constructing an orthonormal basis for the null space using SVD, right? Doesn't scipy have the null_space function that share the same method? link to null_space doc

Yes it does. I wanted to make it evident that I was computing in an orthonormal basis. My question tou in the comments was whether you were sure the authors did?

Well, beside the equation (6) the authors give, they don't provide any thing more about it. In their examples, they only gave results of N. So I don't know if they computed their result in an orthonormal basis or not. Is it a big problem?
